# How to make an Apache server public from my own computer IP address?

Tags: apache, web-services, web, ip, apache2

I've looked everywhere, and have tried many solutions, but have not been able to find the answer to this question.

When I run localhost, I am able to access the default config file in Apache, because the Apache web server is running.

Now what I would like to do, is alter the default config, so that anyone can access the page publicly. I would like to do this with my public ip address, and am not concerned with security, I am more concerned about getting this to work.

What do I have to alter, to achieve this?

The following is my default config file, which is accessed in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```